# Events Manager Issue on Facebook // "Conversion events sending multiple user Client IP Address"

Tags: facebook-conversions-api

I recently received a message from Facebook regarding an issue with a convversion event that I am piping in via a third party. The

The issue error message: Conversion events sending multiple user Client IP Address

Message from Facebook on how to fix the issue:

You'll need to use the solution below to fix the issue.
Once you've fixed the issue in your website code you can mark it as resolved. This will move it to the Previously Detected section. If the issue is found again after 3 days it will move back to the Active section.
In your server payload, send client_ip_address retrieved from customer interactions for RingbaConversion events. Use the payload helper to see how this value should be structured when it's sent to Meta.

I have been running this same conversion with the same pixel for 4 months and recently noticed that conversions were not matching between FB and our Marketing Analytics Platform. Any help with how to resolve would be greatly appreciated!

Conversions recently started to mismatch between Facebook and our marketing analytics platoform, but have been firing at 95% accuracy up until about two weeks ago.